# Developing and simultaneously using own iOS SDKs

Tags: ios, git, git-submodules, git-flow, carthage

Our mobile team has been taking an SDK first approach to developing our new product. We currently have core domain logic within one xcode project, re-usable UI in another, and then a third project that implements the first two as SDKs.

This has served fine under the supervision of one common Github repository, so when a new feature requires changes from all three, the SCM tracks the changes in each and a single PR is submitted.

Now as we approach a release date, the aim is to have the two supporting SDKs be treated as external packages that will be independently versioned and consumed by other clients than ourselves through some form of dependancy manager like Carthage or CocoaPods. To achieve this, we feel that each project deserves it's own independent source control. So we went down the trail of separating code out into different repos.

This presents a problem for local development, whereby a feature requiring changes in all three projects needs some way of submitting a common pull request, without breaking any other usages of the SDK that are relying on the current version.

The two strategies we've come to fall short.

- Separate repos + git submodules
- Local vs. Production dependency references (e.g. Cartfile)

Has anyone had a similar situation, and what strategy did the team use to keep clean histories of each SDK, while also developing across repositories?

Comment: Where is the "Question"? I see the description but what is the question? Did it work or what?

Comment: Hi @Brandon good point. I added a bit towards the end. Hoping this setup resonates with someone who has overcome a similar scenario, and some advice for how to do so. Thanks!